# Proof on ring isomorphism- irreducible

Tags: ring-theory, graph-isomorphism

Consider the ring isomorphism $\phi: A \to B$

I have to prove that $a\in A $ is irreducible if and only if $\phi(a)$ is irreducible.

By definition, $a$ is irreducible in A if and only if:

1) $a$ is no cero

2) $a$ a is not a unit

3) If $a=bc$ where $c,b\in A$, then $b$ or $c$ must be a unit.

To prove $\to$ this direction I have seen that 1) $\phi(a)$ is no cero (by contradiction), and to prove that $\phi(a)$ a is not a unit I have explained the following:

By contradiction, let's suppose that $\phi(a)$ is a unit. So, it exists $b\in A$ where $\phi(a)\phi(b)=1$. As $\phi$ is an homomorpism, $\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(ab)=1$
and $\phi(1)=1$. Therefore, as $\phi$ is inyective,$ab=1$

We get a contradiction as a is not a unit.

Is my proof correct?

Could you help me to prove the 3rd condition, please?
3) If $\phi(a)=\phi(b)\phi(c)$, then $\phi(b)$ or $\phi(c)$ is a unit.

Thank you for your time and dedication.

Comment: If $a=bc$, then $\phi(a) = \phi(b)\phi(c)$, whence $\phi(b)$ or $\phi(c)$ are units. Now check that if $\phi(x)$ is a unit, then $x$ is a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $\phi(a)=\phi(b)\phi(c)=\phi(bc)$. This implies $a=bc$. We know that either $b$ or $c$ is a unit, as $a$ is irreducible. Thus, either $\phi(b)$ or $\phi(c)$ is a unit, as $B^\times=\phi(A^\times)$, where $R^\times$ denotes the group of units in the ring $R$. 
Actually, if you do not want to prove $B^\times=\phi(A^\times)$, you just need $\phi(A^\times)\subset B^\times$, and it is clear that a unit $u\in A^\times$ is sent to a unit (by any ring homomorphism):
$$1_A=uu'\Rightarrow 1_B=\phi(1_A)=\phi(uu')=\phi(u)\phi(u').$$

Comment: When you say that as $b$ or $c$ is a unit, why is either $\phi(b)$ or $\phi(c)$ a unit?

Comment: Because for every ring homomorphism you have $\phi(A^\times)\subset B^\times$, as I showed. This is all you need for the implication $\Rightarrow$, but actually $B^\times = \phi(A^\times)$, as $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Is my 2nd part proof ok?

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine!

Comment: The definition I have used for an irreducible element is when A is an integral domain, but in my exercise they don't mention anything. What happens if A is not an integral domain?

Comment: I think the same works fine, but irreducible elements are usually only defined for domains.